# Can telnet be used to set gps location on real android device connected through usb?

Tags: android, adb, telnet

Can adb be used to alter my android phone's gps location when it is connected through usb? I have installed MockGeoFix on my android phone and enabled it in the mock location setting. I opened a command prompt (Windows 10) and typed

```
telnet 
open 192.168.0.65 5554

MockGeoFix: type 'help' for a list of commands                                                                          
OK

auth                                                                                                                    
KO: Password is not required.

geo fix  40.7127837 -74.0059413 
KO: argument is not a number
```

Also, I am wondering if adb can be used to set the gps location directly and if possible, what is the command I should use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```
geo fix 50 50
```